# IEnumerable print out single entity from a mySQL connection

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc

First of all, im a total beginner with this stuff, so bear with me here.

So, i want to fetch data from a Webservice from xCode. Therefore im building a webservice that can get data in mySql and present them (when im done) in json format.

However, right now, im not very far... 
I have set up my database, and it is live on a server.

I have made the connection string in my web.config, and i have in the code below tried to establish a connection, to try and get and present the row where the ID = 1.. consequently i want it to display all entities in my database, but this is good for a start.

I think my connection is okay, (don't know how to test it, other than just make it print something from the database on my page)

However, i get an error in my code saying

```
cannot implicitly convert type string to 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable<string>'
```

you might say that its an error solved another place on stackoverflow, but none the less i cant seem to understand how to solve it.

```
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        String queryStr;

    public IEnumerable<String> Get()
    {

        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySql"].ToString();
        mySqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

        mySqlConnection.Open();
        queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `CustomerDb` WHERE 'ID' = '1'";
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, mySqlConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        mySqlConnection.Close();

        return queryStr;            
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have made these constructors for my db entities

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are returning the query (a single string) not the result of that query (that you don'even try to read)

Comment: i understand that IEnumerable is an alternative to printing a list, and that i can invoke foreach. but how i would get it to print out my entire table, i have no idea.

Comment: Your method declares that it will return an IEnumerable<string>. not a DataTable. So you should loop over the results obtained by the query and build the IEnumerable to return back to the caller. At this point it is unclear what do you really want to return. If you want to return the whole table CustomerDb then you use the reader to fill a DataTable

Comment: let me just update this, cause i have made constructors for the entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to return a string where your return type of the function Get() is IEnumerable.
I guess you need to get what you select from the table but not your query string, right?

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
    String queryStr;

public IEnumerable<String> Get()
{

    String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySql"].ToString();
    mySqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

    mySqlConnection.Open();
    queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `CustomerDb` WHERE 'ID' = '1'";
    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, mySqlConnection);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader["Name"]; // Assume you want name in your result.
    }

    mySqlConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: preferably i would like my query to be just 

"SELECT * FROM `CustomerDb`" 

i dont understand what your function does?

Comment: it reads the result of your query from the database. I assume your Get() function is trying to return the result but not just the query right?

Comment: im just getting a bunch of errors. What does the sqldatareader do? i mean, wouldnt i just eg. put it inside a foreach loop and print out all entities in xml format?